# Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps does not show street background

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maps, ios-simulator

I'm testing googlemaps using xamarin. Android platforms is ok, but in iOS i cannot see map background. I declared a variable with my credencial in `AppDelegate.cs`

The test only show pin address. The problem is exclusively with the background (street or satellite)

Test on Android OK.

This object receives all information about the location

```
readonly Pin _pinCBC = new Pin()
        {
            Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(Color.Red),
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Label = "61CBC",
            Address = "Washington Avenue",
            Position = new Position(-3.777777, -38.488888),
            ZIndex = 1
        };
```

And this method prints the map on screen. Initialize componente and after add object and positioning the pin to center

```
public MapsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
            map.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = true;

            _pinCBC.IsDraggable = true;
            map.Pins.Add(_pinCBC);
            map.SelectedPin = _pinCBC;
            map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(_pinCBC.Position, Distance.FromMeters(5000)), true);
        }

How could I show background map. Maybe there is any missing property to inform?
```

[iOS Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LKn4.png)

Comment: This probably cause by the key is not setting properly. see [googlemaps-map-not-showing-in-ios](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88461/googlemaps-map-not-showing-in-ios) and [Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/issues/268)

Comment: I've already had a key. But my api key was restricted to Android apps only. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the key for android and iOS is different.